# Embedded Programming, Wait for 12.5 us

Tags: c, embedded, real-time

I'm programming on the [C2000 F28069 Experimenters Kit](http://www.ti.com/tool/tmdxdock28069&DCMP=vissim&HQS=Other+PR+vissim-piccolo-ek-tf-pr). I'm toggling a GPIO output every 12.5 microseconds 5 times in a row. I decided I don't want to use interrupts (though I will if I absolutely have to). I want to just wait that amount of times in terms of clock cycles.

My clock is running at 80MHz, so 12.5 us should be 1000 clock cycles. When I use a loop:

```
for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
```

I get a result that is way too long (not 12.5 us). What other techniques can I use?

Is `sleep(n);` something that I can use on a microcontroller? If so, which header file do I need to download and where can I find it? Also, now that I think about it, `sleep(n);` takes an int input, so that wouldn't even work... any other ideas?

Comment: a while loop generates a loop that runs for more than 1000 clock cycles, because it adds, does the branch, etc... Each thing inside the loop takes more than a single instruction.  Along with that, on various microcontrollers, some instructions take more than a single clock cycle..

Comment: Not to mention that it is nice to know which OS, if any, is there, what other tasks are there, etc.

Comment: @VladLazarenko it's common on microcontrollers to have no OS period, e.g., TinyOS isn't really an OS just some boilerplate code.

Comment: Looks like [TI's libraries include timer queue](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruex3m/spruex3m.pdf) functionality thru `Timer_Params` and `Queue_Handle` with microsecond accuracy (maybe).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use interrupts?  A combination of hardware timer and ISR sounds like exactly what you should use to achieve a well-defined delay on a microcontroller.

Comment: Agree with Oli. I'm a programmer, aspiring hardware hacker and amateur EE, and whenever I talk to real EE friends about their embedded development adventures it seems like their favorite pet peeve is busy wait loops. You're supposed to set a timer, put the thing to sleep and carry on when you get the interrupt.

Comment: +1 for a question that at least named the specific CPU core and execution environment. A few seconds with Google supplied enough detail to know that this is likely bare hardware with no OS on top. The OP clearly has a lot to learn about the embedded world, and should be encouraged to continue asking questions.

Answer (score 8):

Summary: Use the PWM or Timer peripherals to generate output pulses.

First, the clock speed of the CPU has a complex relationship to actual code execution speed, and in many CPUs there is more than one clock rate involved in different stages of the execution. The [chip you reference](http://www.ti.com/product/tms320f28069) has several internal clock sources, for instance. Further, each individual instruction will likely take a different number of clocks to execute, and some cores can execute part of (or all of) several instructions simultaneously.

To rigorously create a loop that required 12.5 µs to execute without using a timing interrupt or other hardware device would require careful hand coding in assembly language along with careful accounting of the execution time of each instruction.

But you are writing in C, not assembler.

So the first question you have to ask is what machine code was actually generated for your loop. And the second question is did you enable the optimizer, and to what level.

As written, a decent optimizer will determine that the loop `for (i=0; i<1000; i++) ;` has no visible side effects, and therefore is just a slow way of writing `;`, and can be completely removed.

If it does compile the loop, it could be written naively using perhaps as many as 5 instructions, or as few as one or two. I am not personally familiar with this particular TI CPU architecture, so I won't attempt to guess at the best possible implementation.

All that said, learning about the CPU architecture and its efficiency is important to building reliable and efficient embedded systems. But given that the chip has peripheral devices built-in that provide hardware support for PWM (pulse width modulated) outputs as well as general purpose hardware timer/counters you would be far better off learning to use the hardware to generate the waveform for you.

I would start by collecting every document available on the CPU core and its peripherals, especially app notes and sample code.

The C compiler will have an option to emit and preserve an assembly language source file. I would use that as a guide to study the structure of the code generated for critical loops and other bottlenecks, as well as the effects of the compiler's various optimization levels.

The tool suite should have a mechanism for profiling your running code. Before embarking on heroic measures in pursuit of optimizations, use that first to identify the actual bottlenecks. Even if it lacks decent profiling, you are likely to have spare GPIO pins that can be toggled around critical sections of code and measured with a logic analyzer or oscilloscope.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One quick follow-up, it makes sense that I can't use the for loop now. But I am still running into difficulties with clock speed. I am using the CPU timer 0 set at a period of 160000 cycles at 80MHz, which should give me a period of 2 ms. But instead, I'm getting  more than 10X that when I look at it on the scope. Also, is there a way to set an interrupt off the values of the timer directly? Or do I have to use a PWM at a different period (12.5 us) and set up an interrupt when the  timer resets? You mention Timer Peripherals, but I'm not sure what my options are other than PWM.

Comment: The clock configuration of that chip is rich in options. If SYSCLKOUT is indeed running at 80MHz, then you have both prescaler and period registers in TIMER0 that together would need to divide by 160000 to achieve a 2ms period. Pay attention to the details, the value loaded is often off by one from the desired period. Read the Technical Reference Manual found at my link above carefully, especially the chapter on TIMER0/1/2 which are timer peripherals other than PWM.

Answer (score 2):

The chip you refer has PWM (pulse width modulation) hardware declared as one of major winning features. You should rely on this. Please refer to appropriate application guide. Generally you cannot guarantee 12.5uS periods from application layer (and should not try to do so). Even if you managed to do so directly from application layer it's bad idea. Any change in your firmware code can break this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a timer peripheral with PWM output capability as suggested by @RBerteig already, then you can generate an accurate timing signal with zero software overhead.  If you need to do other work synchronously with the clock, then you can use the timer interrupt to trigger that too.  However if you process interrupts at an interval of 12.5us you may find that your processor spends a great deal of time context switching rather than performing useful work.

If you simply want an accurate delay, then you should still use a hardware timer and poll its reload flag rather than process its interrupt. This allows consistent timing independent of the compiler's code generation or processor speed and allows you to add other code within the loop without extending the total loop time.  You would poll it in a loop during which you might do other work as well.  The timing jitter and determinism will depend on what other work you do in the loop, but for an empty loop, reaction to the timer even will probably be faster than the latency on an interrupt handler.